# NServiceBus in Azure Deployment Trouble

Tags: c#, nservicebus, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus

I am having some trouble deploying my service into the cloud. More accurately using NServiceBus with Azure. I have retraced my steps 3 times (created the same project 3 times over) with the same results so I am really hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE -> 24/02/2014**
Downgraded assemblies mentioned in post to version 5.1.3 and deployment now works fine and queues are created. Perhaps there is something in the latest version that is causing deployment to fail.

Firstly, I create my prerequisites using the Portal:

- *Cloud Service* entitled **Discount**
- *Storage Account* entitled **discount**
- *Service Bus* entitled **discountbus**

All 3 above were created using *Quick Create*.

Back in Visual Studio, created:

- New *Solution* entitled **AzureTest**
- New *Cloud Service* Project entitled **AzureTest**
- New *Worker Role* project entitled **Discount**

Made references to the following assemblies via nuget:

- NServiceBus 5.2.0
- NServiceBus.Azure 6.2.0
- NServiceBus.Hosting.Azure 6.2.0
- NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus 6.2.0

Added a *new assembly entitled Messages* which will contain my commands and events to be published.

Changed the setting in my cloud service project (AzureTest) to be so that I can get some logging:

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"/>
```

My EndpointConfig looks like:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Worker
{
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Nothing too complicated for now, just anything where the namespace contains commands or events
        configuration.Conventions().DefiningCommandsAs(x => x.AssemblyQualifiedName != null && x.AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains(".Commands."));
        configuration.Conventions().DefiningEventsAs(x => x.AssemblyQualifiedName != null && x.AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains(".Events."));

        configuration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
        configuration.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence>();

        // Docs don't state to do this however logs show this is required
        configuration.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
        configuration.DisableFeature<SecondLevelRetries>();
        configuration.DisableFeature<Sagas>();
    }
}
```

WorkerRole simply attempts to start and stop the NServiceBusRole:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private NServiceBusRoleEntrypoint nsb = new NServiceBusRoleEntrypoint();

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Discount has been started");

        nsb.Start();

        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Discount has stopped");

        nsb.Stop();

        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

ServiceConfiguration.Cloudcscfg contains:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=discount;AccountKey=[my key]" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Config section for NSB:

```
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="5" MaxRetries="2" MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond="0" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Messages" Type="Messages.Commands.TestCommand" Endpoint="Discount" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="Endpoint=sb://discountbus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=[my key]" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I attempt to deploy via right clicking cloud service project and publish I get the following feedback:

> 09:34:29 - Applying Diagnostics extension.
>  09:34:50 - Preparing
>   deployment for AzureTest - 24/02/2015 09:34:20 with Subscription ID
>   'e3dbff72-f1c1-43c8-b052-3404ea5c168e' using Service Management URL
>   'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
>  09:34:50 -
>   Connecting...
>  09:34:50 - Verifying storage account
>   'discount'...
>  09:34:50 - Uploading Package...
>  09:34:56 -
>   Creating...
>  09:35:28 - Created Deployment ID:
>   e464ba5932fc402faf6945e8a983b52e.
>  09:35:28 - Instance 0 of role
>   Discount is stopped
>  09:35:28 - Starting...
>  09:35:45 -
>   Initializing...
>  09:35:45 - Instance 0 of role Discount is in an
>   unknown state
>  09:36:18 - Instance 0 of role Discount is creating
>   the virtual machine
>  09:37:23 - Instance 0 of role Discount is
>   starting the virtual machine
>  09:39:33 - Instance 0 of role
>   Discount is in an unknown state
>  09:40:06 - Instance 0 of role
>   Discount is busy
>   Details: Preparing to start role... System is
>   initializing. [2015-02-24T09:39:43Z]
>  09:42:10 - Instance 0 of role
>   Discount is restarting    Details: Role has encountered an error and has
>   stopped. System was initialized successfully.
>   [2015-02-24T09:41:57Z]
>  09:44:14 - Instance 0 of role Discount is
>   busy  Details: Recovering role... System was in

Tried debugging this locally too with the cloud service project set as start up but get an error stating:

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   WaWorkerHost.exe." Unfortunately no further details are provided.

Server Explorer shows my storage but with only the Metrics Tables showing.

Hoping someone can show me the light and direct me where I have gone wrong. Gotten quite emotional with all this now and been trying to do this simple project for almost 3 days :(

Cheers, DS.

Answer (score 0):

To be more sure of the exception that occurs in azure, you should try to debug it using intellitrace (now named historical debugging I think)

But my gut feeling is that you did not specify which storage account to use for the azure storage persistence that you are enabling.

If you stay stuck, don't hesitate to send me a copy of your test project and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I believe the issue was related to version of NServiceBus I was using. Now I can't be 100% on this but pretty sure this was the case. I was using 5.1.3 but I did a simple package update to 5.2.0 and it worked. It could be a config related issue but I am going to investigate further.